# How can I manipulate this string in order to find and change a section of my original string in Java?

Tags: java, string, string-matching

I am working on a Java application and I have the following problem.

I have a string like this (representing the URL of an API endpoint):

```
https://www.XXX.it/wp-json/custom-api/notary?title=Marina%20Rossi&wpcf-idnotary=089cy5Ra9zE=&wpcf-nome-notary=Marina....................
```

For some reason, I must replace the value of the `idnotary` query parameter with another value. I can do it only directly on this string and not when I am adding parameters, so my question is based on how to perform this string manipulation and not how to add parameters to a request.

Basically, I need a way that starting from this string replace the value after `idnotary=` and before `&wpcf-nome-notary` with another string represented by another variable in my application.

In practice, this value or the previous string `089cy5Ra9zE` must be identified and replaced in the original string (considering that it can change because every request will have a different value).

Comment: One option is to use a pattern with a capture group to do the replacement. `(idnotary=)[^\s&]*` https://regex101.com/r/cJHxkf/1

Comment: You can parse the query string into a map (with the right toolkit), change the value of the right key, then rebuild the query... You can also just use regex/find/replace the usual way. What have you tried?

Comment: @Thefourthbird can you please me help me with some code? I can't figure out what I have to do

Comment: So, what have you tried, and exactly where are you stuck?

Comment: @AndreaNobili You can see some example code here https://regex101.com/r/pmMDSg/1/codegen?language=java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String replaceIdnotary(String url,String newIdnotary){
    return url.replaceAll("(?<=wpcf-idnotary=)[^&]*",newIdnotary);
  }
```